# Created a volume: permission denied to write to /var/foo/

Tags: grafana, docker-for-windows, docker

I have a docker-compose file which creates a volume and grafana... it is working fine on my system, but when a friend executes the script, it says:

```
GF_PATHS_DATA=/var/lib/grafana/ is not writeable
```

The volume is created with this code:

```
volumes:
  - c:/GrafanaData/:/var/lib/grafana/
```

If we change it to

```
volumes:
  - c:/GrafanaData/:/test/
```

It works on his system.

I dont have this error, but he has.

EDIT: we solved it. The problem was that he had drive C as a shared drive, but changed his password. He had to "reassign" the shared drive

Comment: It maybe helpful to show the complete Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml.

Comment: We used the newest grafana image: https://hub.docker.com/r/grafana/grafana/

Answer (score 0):

Does `c:/GrafanaData` exist on his system? Is it writeable?

When you run the image without the volume mounted at `/var/lib/grafana/`, Grafana will be able to write into the empty directory that's there in the image.

Comment: we tried both ways: created before and not created before, but in both times it failed to "mount" to the existing folder /var/lib/grafana